# Get motion used within operatorfunction?

Tags: neovim, map-operator, operator

How can I make a custom operator function that can programmatically reuse the motion that the user called it with?

E.g. I want to map the operator `m` so that `miw` goes to the start of the file and then calls `viwd`, then goes to the end of the file and calls `viwp`. `ma{` should do `ggva{dGva{p`

The only argument that the operator function seems to get is the "type" (characterwise, linewise, or visual), no information available about the motion as far as I can see. So I think perhaps the operator itself has to record the next motion inserted, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The motion information an operator gets is usually information about the actually-selected text, not the literal keystrokes.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble exactly, so that's what I'd like to find out how to read

Comment: I dont think vim's got a way to get the "motion" rather than the position of texts. But still an ugly solution is a loop in opfunc that indefinitively calls `getchar()` and stop until you get your motion. Or use `input` to get the keystrokes but you've to press an extra `<CR>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `'[` and `']` marks to get the boundaries of the motion.
The `"line"/"block"/"char"` passed to the operatorfunc is used to know where to take full lines and where not to.

It is not possible to directly get the motion character as far as I now.